# Google Chrome Delphi

Tags: html, delphi-7

Добрый вечер,хочу создать как-бы клиент для сайта
Например на сайте есть такой код(html):

```
<li id="helloUser">Приветствуем вас на сайте, <b>НИК!</b></li>
```

Хочу что бы при открытии программы текст "Приветствуем вас на сайте,НИК!" выводился в memo,или же в другие элементы.

Comment: 1. Находим что-то для парсинга `html` в `delphi`.
2. Парсим страницу, находим тег с нужным `id`.
3. Берём содержимое нужного тега и выводим его в нужном `Memo`

Comment: А при чем тут гугл хром?